# Check if variable exists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to print a dictionary to screen, however, prior to its creation I want it to display nothing ("").

```
def dictionarysubmit():
    Letter = entry2.get()
    Rule = entry3.get()
    global grammar
    grammar = {}
    grammar[Letter] = Rule
##    print (grammar)
```

This is the creation of the dictionary, however is only prompt on button click.

I am currently trying:

```
cr = {}
if grammar in globals:
    cr = grammar
else:
    cr = {}
```

> NameError: name 'grammar' is not defined

Is the error I am getting, I understand that grammar is not defined upon execution of the programme.

Comment: Use a `try ... except` block, keyed on `NameError`

Comment: @Prune Or just give `grammar` a default value of `{}`.

Comment: Yes, why not use a `try ... except` block and if it does not exist then handle it in the `except` part.

Comment: Thanks to @Anthon for the reference.  First use of my shiny, new `dupe-hammer`.  :-)

Comment: Don't write your program in such a way. Initialize `grammer = None` and test for `grammer is None`.

Comment: That's not true. You can easily check if `grammar` exists--check the duplicate link.

Comment: Thank you all :)